# How to insertAdjacentHTML between 2 different divs

Tags: javascript, html, insertadjacenthtml

I need to get my *div* between 2 *divs* inside my template. I can only edit it with external HTML, JS.
Template looks like this:

```
<main id="content-in">
    <div id="homepage-banner"> XXX </div>
    <div id="carousel-banner"> XXX </div>
```

And I need to get my *img* and *a href* `<div id="moveOut"> XXX </div>` between these 2.

I have it like this now which works ok:

```
<script>
function addCode() {
    var d1 = document.getElementById('content-in');
    d1.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div id="moveOut"><a href="https://example.com/"><img src="https://example.png" alt=""></a></div>');
        }
</script>
```

but I need to move it.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert after the `homepage-banner` DIV.

```
var d1 = document.getElementById("homepage-banner");
d1.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div id="moveOut"><a href="https://example.com/"><img src="https://example.png" alt=""></a></div>');
```

Comment: Oh my god, you are right, I'm doing this website for 7 days, a whole day and I just found this method today and I think I didn't get it until now.
Thank you.